# How can I configure ZSH's vi mode to persist the state between commands?

Tags: shell, zsh, vi-mode, zle

I am aware how to set ZSH's default line editor to use vi-like keybindings...

```
bindkeys -v
```

...and even to default each new prompt to be in command mode instead of insert mod by default...

```
zle-line-init() { zle -K vicmd; }
zle -N zle-line-init
```

...and most of the time I prefer this behavior. However, it makes a few things very awkward. For example pasting multi-line commands into a terminal for immediate execution becomes nearly impossible.

**How can I configure it so that the mode is persistent?** I would like whatever mode it was when I executed one line should be the default mode for the next line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe like:

```
vicmd-accept() { prev_mode=vicmd; zle .accept-line }
viins-accept() { prev_mode=viins; zle .accept-line }
zle-line-init() { zle -K ${prev_mode:-viins} }
zle -N viins-accept
zle -N vicmd-accept
zle -N zle-line-init
bindkey -M viins \\r viins-accept
bindkey -M vicmd \\r vicmd-accept
```

Or even simpler:

```
accept-line() { prev_mode=$KEYMAP; zle .accept-line }
zle-line-init() { zle -K ${prev_mode:-viins} }
zle -N accept-line
zle -N zle-line-init
```

Comment: I see what you did there. Subtle ;-)